# Spring TaskExecutor Transaction Lost (Proxy vs. Direct call)

Tags: spring, proxy, transactions

I try to get the TaskExecutor (ThreadPoolTaskExecutor) to work for a currently well working service with Transactions but when i start the Task the existing Transaction is not found anymore.

(When below start() Method is called there is already a transaction active)
(The SimplePOJO ist out of context and just holds some data lets say to be stored in the DB)

```java
@Component
@Transactional(rollbackFor = { Exception.class })
public class MyService {

    @Autowired
    MyTaskRunner myTaskRunner;

    public void start() {

        // TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() -> true

        SimplePOJO pojo = new SimplePOJO();
        myTaskRunner.executeTask(pojo);
    }
}
```

Above Service uses this Component:

```java
@Component
public class MyTaskRunner implements ApplicationContextAware {

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext = null;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        MyTaskRunner.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

    public void executeTask(SimplePOJO simplePOJO) {

        // TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive() -> true

        MyDelegate myDelegate = applicationContext.getBean(MyDelegate.class);
        myDelegate.setSimplePOJO(simplePOJO);
        taskExecutor.execute(myDelegate);
    }
}
```

That gets a ThreadPoolTaskExecutor configured this way:

```xml
<bean id="taskExecutor"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="1" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="5" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="25" />
</bean>
```

And should finally start the Async work in a new transaction per task:

```java
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class MyDelegate implements Runnable {

    private SimplePOJO simplePOJO;

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()); -> False!

        if (this.simplePOJO != null) {
            this.doStuff(angebotAnfrageContainer);
        }
    }

    public void setSimplePOJO(SimplePOJO simplePOJO) {
        this.simplePOJO = simplePOJO;
    }

    @Async
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void doStuff() {

        // TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()); -> False!

        // do stuff with the pojos data in the transaction (persist on DB)
    }

}
```

Do you have any suggestions what i am missing here?

Very many thanks in advance!

**What i tried**
Wrote above code & searched the web for hours, this is what i found out:

I have to admit i am very new to Spring and havent yet understood the framework too well. Within the last few hours of trying and searching the web i think it has something to do with Proxys beeing created from spring and that chain breaks when i call the execute()-Method or when the TaskRunner calls the run()-Method that instead of calling the Proxy calls the Implementation (MyDelegate) directly ... but i have absolutly no idear how i could verify or change that.

Very many thanks in advance

Comment: Spring uses proxies and proxies will only work for external method calls. Your run method calls the method with the `@Transactional` however this is always from within the proxy, so no transaction is ever going to be started.

Comment: Very many thanks for your reply. I think i understood that... what would you recomend? 

(I will now try to have the doStuff()-method in another Spring-Bean and call this from the run()-Method)

Comment: O.k. you input was the key and i could solve it by having above doSomething()-Method in a own Component which then gets called from the run()-Method. After all this trying and stuff i need to rethink if i even need the @Async anymore ;)

Comment: Dont hesitate to make it an anwer so i can accept & upvote it :)
Just simple stuff may be absolutly clear for ppl with Spring knowledge but not Junior Developpers that just startet it like i am

Comment: Why not simply put it on the `run` method why add additional complexity. Also you don't need the `@Async` because you are scheduling it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transactions are applied using AOP. Spring, by default, uses [proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies) to apply AOP. The usage of proxies result in only calls into (external method calls) the object are intercepted. In your case you are doing a method call from inside the object which will not pass through the proxy and will not be intercepted, basically rendering your `@Transactional` useless.

Simply moving the `@Transactional` to the `run` method should fix your problem as the `run` method will now run in a transaction.

```
@Transactional
public void run() {...}
```

You can also remove the `@Async` as that doesn't do anything here, you are executing task with a `TaskExecutor` already making them async (depending on which [`TaskExecutor`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor) you use).

Links:

1. [Understanding AOP Proxies](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-understanding-aop-proxies)
2. [TaskExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-task-executor)

Comment: If i do the @Transactional on the run()-method i get a BeanNotOfRequiredTypeException: Bean named 'myDelegate' must be of type [MyDelegate], but was actually of type [$Proxy86]

Comment: You are right you should use classbased proxies instead of interface based proxies if you want that. Spring by default uses interface based proxies.