# Spring 4: ThreadPoolTaskExecutor transaction management issue

Tags: spring-transactions, threadpoolexecutor, spring-4

We recently upgraded our spring version to 4.x from 2.x which started causing some issues with one of our 'threadpooltaskexecutor' implementation.

The implementation was as below:

```
public class A
{
..............................
..............................

public void create()
{
    this.threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            createABCAsync();
        }
     });
}


public void createABCAsync()
{
    createABC();
}


public void createABC()
{
    .....................................
    ..................................... 
    abcDAO.saveOrUpdate(abc);
    xyzDAO.saveOrUpdate(xyz);
}
```

...................................................
 ...................................................
}

The bean definitions for class A has entries like below:

```
`<bean id="clsIntegrationManager" parent="txProxyTemplate"`>
  .................................................
  .................................................
    <property name="transactionAttributes">
        <props>
              <prop key="create">PROPAGATION_REQUIRED</prop>                   
              <prop key="createABCAsync">PROPAGATION_REQUIRES_NEW</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
```

After spring upgrade, the above code threw an exception as below:

```
Exception in thread "threadPoolTaskExecutor-1" org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Write operations are not allowed in read-only mode (FlushMode.MANUAL): Turn your Session into FlushMode.COMMIT/AUTO or remove 'readOnly' marker from transaction definition.
```

To resolve the above I added an entry like follows in the DAO layer bean definition file:

```
<bean id ="hibernateTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTemplate">
<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
<property name="checkWriteOperations" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

The above entry resolved the exception, but the asynchronous method execution which starts a separate transaction using REQUIRES_NEW is not doing any database commits. We have a couple of 'saveOrUpdate()' calls inside the createABC() method but nothing gets saved in database.

Can someone please help in understanding what is going wrong above ?

I tried a few different solution approaches, one of which is described here: [[Spring TaskExecutor Transaction Lost (Proxy vs. Direct call)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388088/spring-taskexecutor-transaction-lost-proxy-vs-direct-call][1])  but this did not help.

Comment: createABCASync is called from another internal class method createABC hence a new transaction would NOT be started. Are you sure it worked before in spring 2? Strange

Comment: Hi Andy, can you please suggest some way to handle the above scenario? It was working for me with Spring 2.x

Comment: You need to inject the ClassA bean instance in the same class - Self injection and then call classA.createABCAsync() so that a new transaction gets created. Enable spring transaction package logs for verifying that the transaction actually gets started.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. Can you please help on how I can perform a self injection using setter mechanism? My spring configuration is xml based and not Annotation based